# .htaccess, Can someone please explain what does this code do?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]+)$
    RewriteRule ^produktysearchdu\.php$ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+) produktysearchdu.php rw=1&search=$1 [L,QSA]
    ErrorDocument 404 https://www.google.sk
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Apache has a pretty good manual about their rewrite directives: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Is this code even working? like Magnus said you should first study rewrite directives!

Answer (score 1):

If Apache's Mod Rewrite is available

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Turn Rewrite On so we can use it

```
RewriteEngine On
```

If the url query string starts with `search=` and `search=` has a value

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]+)$
```

If the condition above (search=*) is met
...and the url matches the php file below
... remove the query string (that's the question mark)
... and redirect to the match from above `%1` using a 301

```
RewriteRule ^produktysearchdu\.php$ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

This is a separate rule which looks broken
... there should probably be a `?` between `.php` and `rw=1`
... to then send any urls to the file below for parsing

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) produktysearchdu.php rw=1&search=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Defines what to show if a 404 is triggered

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.google.sk
```

End the section

```
</IfModule>
```